# How to save errors with the handleError in CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, handleerror

I have a big problem. Well, I'm trying to save the errors that happen in my web application. For example (only a example), if I make a division by zero, or happens an error in a query or something like that. So, I wanna catch that and save it in the database. But the handleError of CakePHP is static, so I can't use $this->MyModel->saveError(...).

In my /app/Lib/AppError.php I have this:

```
class AppError extends ErrorHandler
{
     public $uses = array('Errors.Error');

     public static function handleError($code, $description, $file = null, $line = null, $context = null)
     {
         //This print the error:
         echo "Code: ".$code." Description: ".$description." File: ".$file." Line: ".$line."<br>";
         //I want to do this, (save to the database):
         $this->Error->saveError($code, $description, $file, $line);

     }
}
```

Without the $this->Error->saveError($code, $description, $file, $line); it works but I not only want to show the error.
I think need an example or something like that. Please help me.
Regards and thank you.
Thanks...
P.D.: Sorry for the English, I'm an english student...

Comment: So where is the property `Error`? :) .. and you are sorry for your english for being an english student? Hmm ok ;)

Comment: Well, 'Error' is my Model. That should save the error in a table, but the problem is that cake says: Using $this when not in object context File: /var/www/industrialProcess/app/Lib/AppError.php

Answer (score 0):

You defined the function `handelError` as a static function, therefor the variable `$this` does not exist, because a static environment cannot know the object it refers to, only its classname. In a static environment, `self::` has to be used instead of `$this`, e.g.

`self::Error->saveError($code, $description, $file, $line);`

This also means that the property `Error` has to be declared `static`.